# Update a DIV with a Partial View on Button Click (dynamic)

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc, partial-views

So I want to do something almost exactly like you find here:
http://www.makeitspendit.com/calling-asp-mvc-controllers-from-jquery-ajax/

It will do exactly what I want it to do, but having the same script written out for all 4 buttons is not very DRY. (Well, not DRY at all)

I would like to have one script to call the correct view based on the ID of the button, so that code would only have to be on my page once.
I tried passing this.id into the function call, and using concatenation in the "url:" property of the ajax call but that doesn't work.
EXAMPLE:

```
<div id="projectDiv">

<button onclick="loadProject(this.id)" id="_Project1">Project 1</button>
<button onclick="loadProject(this.id)" id="_Project2">Project 2</button>

<script>    
    function loadProject(projectID) {
          $.ajax({
            url: ("/Projects/Project/"+projectID),
            datatype: "text",
            type: "POST",
            success: function (data) {
              $('#projectDiv').html(data);
            },
          });
        });
</script>
```

And in the controller:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Project(string id)
{
    return View(id);
}
```

I've searched all over for this and found similar things (but not similar enough to derive what I need) but couldn't find this scenario -- which I would've assumed was common enough to have more information.

The example code illustrates how I would LIKE it to work, but I can't seem to pass the variable into the url property like that. While I am admittedly pretty new to ASP.NET MVC, this seems like it should be pretty basic and yet I've been stuck on this for a minute.

Comment: _doesn't work_ isn't descriptive enough to help you. What happens instead? Are there any error messages in the browser's console? Can you reach a debug stop in your controller action?

Comment: Your returning a view (and it should be `return PartialView()` so its `dataType: 'html'` (not `text`) and you making a post so use `url: '@Url.Action("Project", "Projects")', data: { id: projectID }`

Comment: Use `PartialViewResult` instead of `ActionResult` and `return PartialView()` and you don't required using `[HttpPost]`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I realize this post is over a year old at this point, but I wanted to add a more complete answer based off the comments made on the original question, in case others like me stumble across it.

In my `/Views/Shared/` folder I have `_YourPartialName.cshtml`

In my `HomeController.cs` I have:

```
[HttpPost]
public PartialViewResult AddPartialToView(string id)
{
    return PartialView(id);
}
```

In my `MainView.cshtml` I have:

```
...
<div id="placeHolderDiv">          
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    <button class="btn" type="button" onclick="replaceContentsOfDiv(this.id)" id="_YourPartialName">Add A Partial View Above This</button>
</div>
...
<script>
    function replaceContentsOfDiv(partialViewToInsert) {
        $.ajax({
            url: '@Url.Action("AddPartialToView", "Home")',
            data: { id: partialViewToInsert},
            type: "POST",
            success: function(data) {
                $('#placeHolderDiv').html(data);
            }
        });
    }
</script>
```

This will result in:

```
<div id="placeHolderDiv">
    <whatever class="you had in your partial">
    </whatever>
</div>
```

Hope this helps.