# Model Binding a View Component in Razor Pages

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, razor-pages, asp.net-core-viewcomponent

I'm using ASP.NET Core 2.1, Razor Pages, and a View Component (though I'm not sold if View Components are needed yet)

I have a parent Model, `Organization`, that contains a list of child Models, `Contacts`:

**Organization**

```
public Guid Id { get; set; }
public string OrganizationName { get; set; }

public ICollection<Contact> Contacts { get; set; }
```

**Contact**

```
public Guid Id { get; set; }
public string ContactName { get; set; }
public Guid OrganizationId { get; set; }
```

What I'm trying to do is have a list of n number of Contacts in Organization that I can add and delete from a View and have that reflected when I hit my `OnPost()` Page Model method

---

In my previous project, an MVC5 web app:

- I used Ajax to add Partial Views to a view: [Update a DIV with a Partial View on Button Click (dynamic)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39186120/update-a-div-with-a-partial-view-on-button-click-dynamic/47559138#47559138)
- And I was able to get at least one level deep lists to return to the Controller: [C# MVC, Link Together Nested Partial Views](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47912801/c-sharp-mvc-link-together-nested-partial-views)

The combination of those two looks a lot like this: [MVC 5 BeginCollectionItem with Partial CRUD](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29774822/mvc-5-begincollectionitem-with-partial-crud/29869344#29869344)

---

**Current status**

In `~/ViewComponents/Contact.cs` I have:

```
public class Contact : ViewComponent
{
    private readonly ApplicationDbContext _context;

    public Contact(ApplicationDbContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }

    public async Task<IViewComponentResult> InvokeAsync(Guid organizationId, Guid contactId)
    {
        var contact = new Models.Contact { Id = contactId, OrganizationId = organizationId };
        return View(contact);
    }
}
```

Which invokes `~/Pages/Shared/Components/Contact/Default.cshtml`, [uses a ported version of BeginCollectionItem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38864912/using-begincollectionitem-in-asp-net-core):

```
@model Models.Contact

@using (Html.BeginCollectionItem("Contacts"))
{
    <div class="row">
        <input asp-for="Id" type="hidden" />
        <input asp-for="OrganizationId" type="hidden"/>
        <input asp-for="ContactName" class="form-control"/>
    </div>
}
```

I'm then directly loading this in Organiztion's `~/Pages/Organizations/Create.cshtml`:

```
@page
@using System.Linq
@using ViewComponents
@model CreateModel

@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Create";
}

<h2>Create</h2>

<h4>Organization</h4>
<hr />
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <form method="post">
            <div class="form-group">
                <input asp-for="Organization.OrganizationName" class="form-control" />
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="OrganizationContacts" class="col-form-label"></label>
  <!-- HERE --> @await Component.InvokeAsync(nameof(ViewComponents.Contact), new { organizationId = Model.Organization.Id, contactId = Guid.NewGuid() })
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-primary" />
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

When I click the Submit button, it hits the `OnPostAsync()` method in `Create.cshtml.cs`:

```
public class CreateModel : PageModel
{
    private readonly ApplicationDbContext _context;

    [BindProperty]
    public Organization Organization { get; set; }

    public CreateModel(ApplicationDbContext context, IMapper mapper)
    {
        _context = context;
    }

    public IActionResult OnGet()
    {
        Organization = new Organization{ Contacts = new List<Contact>() };
        return Page();
    }

    public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostAsync()
    {
        _context.Organizations.Add(Organization); // <--- Always has an empty Contacts list
        await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

        return RedirectToPage("./Index");
    }
}
```

When I hit `OnPostAsync`, the bound `Organization` Model has it's `OrganizationName` value just fine, but the `Contacts` list is always empty.

How can I add a Contact to Organization's `Contacts` list knowing that later I want to have n number of Contacts added or removed?

Most answers I've seen to this kind of question have `for` loops, but they require me to know ahead of time how many Contacts are or will be in an Organization and that simply isn't the case for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For resolving empty `Contacts`, try to change `Html.BeginCollectionItem("Contacts")` to `Html.BeginCollectionItem("Organization.Contacts")`.

Since `Contacts` is collection of `Organization`, you need to pass `Organization.Contacts[index].Property`, otherwise, it will fail to bind the request to model.

Comment: It's always the little things, isn't it? Thanks!